# There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oledb

I am getting an error at the `ExecuteNonQuery` and really don't know why. I spent a lot of time searching the web and realized that `User` has to be between `[]`, but it hasn't solved my problem.

```
else {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Email = '" + tbMail.Text + "'";
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
    int count = adapter.Fill(table);
    if (count != 0)    {
        MessageBox.Show("This email is already in use", "Email in use", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    } else {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        string encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tbPass.Text)));

        connection.Open();

        string command = "INSERT INTO [User] (Username, Password, Email) VALUES('" + tbUser.Text + "', '" + encryptedPassword + "', " + tbMail.Text + ")";
        insertCommand.Connection = connection;
        insertCommand.CommandText = command;
        adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The error is:

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]"

Comment: `" + tbMail.Text + "` must be `'" + tbMail.Text + "'` But use parameters instead, that also prevents you from sql-injection attacks.

Comment: What is the content of command before it is executed?   You could take that SQL string and execute it manually to find the error.  By the way, building SQL strings like that makes you prone to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Your email value must be between quotes, just like username and password.

Another point is that you should use sql parameters to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: @ForgottenSemicolon I just can't help myself :-)

Comment: string command = "INSERT INTO [User] (Username, Password, Email) VALUES('" + tbUser.Text + "', '" + encryptedPassword + "', " + tbMail.Text + ")"; needs quotes on last value.

Comment: @Leeish That is indeed the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips, I'm going to do the sql parameters right away.